# Having trouble getting ARP requests through a QEMU VM on Mac OSX

Tags: linux, networking, macos, virtual-machine, qemu

Using Mac OS 10.14.5 Mojave and QEMU version 4.0.0

I'm trying to get an Ubuntu Server 19.04 guest running with network communication through a bridge on my Mac host. At the moment I'm struggling with even a ping from guest to host and vice-versa.

I created a bridge on the host with:

```
sudo ifconfig bridge1 create
sudo ifconfig bridge1 192.168.100.1/24 up
```

and also set the sys flags `net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` and `net.link.ether.inet.proxyall=1` although I'm not sure if they're necessary at this point in the project.

The VM is started with:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu-test -cdrom ubuntu-19.04-live-server-amd64.iso -accel hvf -netdev tap,br=/dev/bridge1,script=/etc/qemu-ifup,downscript=/etc/qemu-ifdown,id=net0 -device e1000,netdev=net0 -m 512
```

Where the qemu-ifup script has:

```
ifconfig bridge1 addm tap0
```

I set the ip of the vm with netplan via:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.100.2/24
      gateway4: 192.168.100.1
```

and netplan apply.

I populate the ARP tables of the host & guest manually with the MAC addresses of the network devices in question:

```
_gateway (192.168.100.1) at $BRIDGE_MAC [ether] PERM on ens3
```

```
? (192.168.100.2) at $GUEST_DEV_MAC on bridge1 ifscope permanent [bridge]
```

on the guest and host respectively where $GUEST_DEV_MAC and $BRIDGE_MAC are the MAC addresses of the two devices in question.

On the guest ufw is disabled iptables -S returns:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

When I run tcpdump on the host and try to ping it from the guest I can see ICMP echo requests and replies, but they do not make it to the guest:

```
$GUEST_DEV_MAC > $BRIDGE_MAC, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.100.2 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 1181, seq 2, length 64
$BRIDGE_MAC > $GUEST_DEV_MAC, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.100.2: ICMP echo reply, id 1181, seq 2, length 64
```

where $GUEST_DEV_MAC and $BRIDGE_MAC are the MAC addresses of the two devices in question.

When I try to ping the guest from the host I only get:

```
$BRIDGE_MAC > $GUEST_DEV_MAC, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.100.2: ICMP echo request, id 48948, seq 1, length 64
```

I'm at a loss for what could be preventing traffic between these, but my experience is very limited. If any more information is required for debugging let me know, and if anyone has experience enough to shed some light on what could be done to fix the connection feel free to answer. Thanks.

Comment: You created the bridge but you may need to turn it on.  Look at `ip link show bridge1` and see if it says UP or DOWN.  If it says DOWN do a `ip link set dev bridge1 up`.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question - bridge was up, not sure if it would generate an ICMP echo reply otherwise.

Comment: Debugging usually works by making things simpler, and then investigating the simpler variants to see why it doesn't work. So the first thing I'd do is to take the bridge out of the picture, start the VM with just the tap device, give the tap device on the host and the corresponding internal device in the VM two addresses in the same subnet, and see if ping works. If it does, the next step is to manually add the tap device to the bridge and see if that works. Then you can automate it.